# How do I force drop and re-create a selected table in code-first migration?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I want to drop a table with a thousand columns and let migration re-create it. 
I can issue a

```
    DropTable("MyTableWithManyColumns");
```

But the problem is I would do a manual create table like this

```
    CreateTable(
            "dbo.MyTable",
            c => new
                {
                    RowId = c.Int(nullable: false, identity: true),
                    // many columns follow...
                })
            .PrimaryKey(t => t.RowId);
```

The easier way to do this is use SSMS and right click Drop Create Table to new window and execute from there.

But is there is there an easy way using code migration?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I can see two possible ways:

1. Drop the table from database
2. Generate a new migration (using `Add-Migration`). A new migration that creates the missing table will be generated
3. Execute Migration (using `Update-Database`)

OR

1. Remove the entity from the context (remember to remove all relationships with others entities)
2. Generate a Migration using `Add-Migration` (it will generate a drop table method)
3. Execute Migration using `Update-Database`
4. Add the entity to the context
5. Generate a new Migration using `Add-Migration` (it will generate a create table method)
6. Execute Migration using `Update-Database`

Hope it helps!

Comment: This doesn't always work. Dropped tables can be very difficult to recreate.

Comment: DO NOT USE OPTION 1! EF will not pick up a random manually dropped table from the database.

Comment: If you've already done what @Ben said, and you have a sad. Just go into your migrations folder and remove the `CreateTable` code that represents your deleted table.

Comment: What about the fact that the EF compares with a snapshot, and not with a database?

Answer (score 9):

There is another option for this:

1. Manually drop tables you want to recreate
2. Remove records from "__EFMigrationsHistory" table that are linked to your deleted tables
3. Run "update-database"

It should run all migrations that are not in history once again. Be careful with this if you have migrations that touches more than one table. You may need to omit some migrations and than add changes manually.

Deleting DbSets from Context should also work and is probably better, but for me in Entity-Framework-Core it hasn't worked at all.

Comment: This is work for me just remember to delete migration history from both code side and also from the database __MigrationHistory table

Answer (score 0):

No programmatic way that I've determined.  Not from lack of trying though.

Here's my success though:

In SQL Management Studio I generated scripts for the entire database (or tables you know are related).  I found any foreign key (FK) constraints, indexes, etc. related to MyTable.  Also generate sql insert statements for MyTable.  Drop the constraints, drop the table, create the table (obviously with the appropriate field order), insert data, re-create FK constraints.

Just to test the db I tried making a database change.

```
ADD-MIGRATION XYZ
UPDATE-DATABASE -VERBOSE
```

Everything was working.

Answer (score -3):

1. Delete Migration folder with sub content.
2. Than manually delete tables
3. Run update-database command from package manager console

Everything will work properly
Happy coding

Comment: Is this a joke? you might as well suggest to delete the project and create a new one...

Comment: At that point just use the command `Drop-Database` 